# Updating a single item in a Javascript (Vue.js) object within a list array

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

I have a list of gallery images and I want to be able to select an image to make it `preview: true` By default, there always has to be a preview image. 
What I am trying to is

1. Click the image
2. Remove the preview on all images
3. Make the clicked image a preview
4. Update API

This is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
export default {
    props: ['images'],
    methods: {
        makePreview (image, index) {

            // Loop through images and remove preview
            this.images.map((image, index) => {
                image.preview = false
            })

            // Set clicked image to preview
            image.preview = true

            // Update API
            this.updateImages()
        }
    }
}
```

When I `console.log(image)` in the method, I do get the correct image object to update, but this is not updating the `images` prop.

EDIT:

Image object:

```
{
    alt: "New venue"
    id: 111
    large: "https://radnomcdn.com/large.jpg"
    order: 2
    preview: false
    thumb: "https://radnomcdn.com/thumb.jpg"
}
```

Comment: What does the `images` property contain? The exact structure?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: I need the preview to be true on the one selected while turning the other off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what we are missing here in your question, this code seems to work. The only main difference I see is I commented out the `updateImages` method.

Technically, this is a situation where you are mutating a property, which is generally frowned upon. The intention is that properties are passed down and changes to those properties are emitted as events back to the parent. However, objects and arrays can be mutated.

```js
const images = [{
    alt: "New venue",
    id: 111,
    large: "https://radnomcdn.com/large.jpg",
    order: 2,
    preview: false,
    thumb: "https://radnomcdn.com/thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    alt: "New venue",
    id: 222,
    large: "https://radnomcdn.com/large.jpg",
    order: 3,
    preview: false,
    thumb: "https://radnomcdn.com/thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    alt: "New venue",
    id: 333,
    large: "https://radnomcdn.com/large.jpg",
    order: 4,
    preview: false,
    thumb: "https://radnomcdn.com/thumb.jpg"
  }

]

Vue.component("display-images", {
  template:`
    <div>
      <div v-for="image, index in images">
        {{image.preview}}
        <button @click="makePreview(image, index)">Preview</button>  
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['images'],
  methods: {
    makePreview(image, index) {

      // Loop through images and remove preview
      this.images.map((image, index) => {
        image.preview = false
      })

      // Set clicked image to preview
      image.preview = true

      // Update API
      //this.updateImages()
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.makePreview(this.images[0])
  }
})

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data:{
   images
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <display-images :images="images"></display-images>
  <div style="margin-top:5em">{{images}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see yours is working, which I why I'm getting confused on mine. Unless it's because I need to update it as an event. Let me try that.

Comment: It's an API call to update the list that I have commented out until I can update the property first.

Comment: If you want to share the code in a gist or pastebin or something I'll see if I can see the issue.

Comment: Sure https://gist.github.com/jackbarham/0ab318fd35499dd4366cb3194421fcfc

Comment: Everything else works (drag drop, deleting, etc) execpt that

Comment: @JackBarham I think Draggable is screwing you up somehow. I removed it and this works. https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KnVJlX22P0M6mkbpt19

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's not made a difference. I'm going to look at events.